# Crawl jquery loaded content with HtmlWeb.Load

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

have this question in mind. I'm able to retrieve all the information of a website well, except for the information which is (I guess) loaded with Jquery after I received the content-reponse.

Is there a way to get this dynamatically loaded content as well? I already tried to search this on Google and here, but can't figure out how to discribe my problem very well..

**Simple situation:**
I have this site with information of cars : http://www.autowiki.nl/autovergelijker
There are different dropdownlists, the most important is for example 'merk' (car brands)
When I select a car brand the dropdown of the models has been filled with the matching brands (and this changes the url as well)

So if I visit the site http://www.autowiki.nl/autovergelijker/#merk_1=15 then I see in my browser that the dropdown of brands contains 'Hyundai' and the dropdown models contains the matching Hyundai Models

**What I want**
To read out all of the models in the dropdownlist models

**My code**

```
Dim page as HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
Dim doc as HtmlDocument = page.Load('http://www.autowiki.nl/autovergelijker/#merk_1=15')
Dim crawlstring as String = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[@id='model_1']").InnerHtml
```

**What I got**
The Crawlstring contains one option which is '---' of empy. And not the matching models

Answer (score 0):

With C#

`var list=new List<yourVar>();var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.autowiki.nl/autovergelijker/#merk_1=15");
var xpath = "//select[@id='model_1']//option[@value]";foreach (HtmlNode Node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)){
var yourVar=Node.Attributes["value"].Value;list.Add(yourVar);}`